# Scifi fantasy book 1980s or 1990s

Tags: story-identification

I read a book years ago that was about a hunchbacked boy. I remember there was space travel, a ship, a female and other characters.

I also remember he had an incredible itching on his hump. He was helping someone then his hump split open and he had wings. His name was Fayrei or Fayrie, I can't remember what he was called before he told his name.

There was a sequel when he started looking for his own kind.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like *[Flight in Yiktor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0416074324)*, by Andre Norton.  The third of five books in the Moon Singer series.  The character's name is Farree.  When he is found by two characters from the first two books, Krip and Maelen, he is called Dung.

[image: Book cover]

[Goodreads summary](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1026540.Flight_In_Yiktor)

> A psychic sorceress, a telepathic adventurer, and deformed ex-slave use their extrasensory powers to stop an intergalactic organization of thieves from looting the planets.

Comment: Thats it! Thanknyou so much!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thank you for adding the cover - the copy I have has a very dull cover of some mountains with one tiny winged figure in the distance!

Comment: @NiceOrc: Not at all. I generally just go to Goodreads and grab the first cover they show. If the querent has stated their cover looks a particular way, I click into the alternate editions to try to find one that matches. It's amazing the difference a picture can make. :)