# Book about an alien boy sold because his species grows wings

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I'm trying to recall a book I read in the 1990's. A smuggler or pirate (human) has a child alien he's raising to adulthood to sell its wings. The alien is the main character, he's a hunchback with no idea of his true nature. The story is his escape and in the final chapter his back finally splits open and his wings spring forth.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37953/scifi-fantasy-book-1980s-or-1990s (which has an unaccepted answer that is confirmed via OP comment)

Answer (score 4):

'Flight In Yiktor' by Andre Norton. The child is called Farree, although he is known as Dung. In a sequel, 'For Fear Of Little Men'; he and his companions search for his home planet.